# Different behaviour in elasticsearch with two different indexes

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, mapping

I have two different behaviours with two queries that are exactly the same.

In my first query the **must_not** clause is not filtering **brand3** and **brand4** is returning brand3 and brand4 products. However the second query the must_not is working.

**First query:**

```
GET firstindex/product/_search
{  
            "filter":{
                "bool": {
                    "should": [   
                      {"bool": {
                            "must_not":{ "terms": {"brand.raw": ["brand3,brand4"]}
                            },
                            "must":{
                                "term" : {"retailer" : "retailer1"}    
                            }
                         }
                      }
                    ]
                }    
            }

    ,
    "size":10000
}
```

**Second query:**

```
GET secondindex/product/_search
{  
            "filter":{
                "bool": {
                    "should": [   
                       {"bool": {
                            "must_not": { "terms": {"brand.raw": ["brand1,brand2"]}
                            },
                            "must":{
                                "term" : {"retailer" : "retailer2"}    
                            }
                         }
                      }
                    ]
                }    
            }

    ,
    "size":10000
}
```

**The mapping for brand is:**

```
 "brand":{
                  "type":"string",
                  "fields":{
                     "raw":{
                        "type":"string",
                        "index":"not_analyzed"
                     }
                  }
               }
```

I got stuck, what I can do to know what is happening?

**UPDATE**

As well I tried to create a new index from firstindex to first_index but it doesn't work. Finally I could fix this changing recreating the index using brand_name instead of brand. I know that I didn't the origin of the problem but this worked.

Comment: the first clause has **brand3,brand4** in the filter was it meant to be 1 & 2 ?

Comment: What @keety said + you have two different retailers, i.e. `retailer1` and `retailer2`... What results are you expecting?

Comment: Can you provide a sample output for both

Comment: @Val the results that I am expecting is not retrieve products with a specific brand if "brand" is in the must_not clause and this is not happening in the first query.

Comment: Can you try with POST instead of GET?

Comment: @Val I have executed with POST and it's doing the same. Do you have any tip? I don't have any idea what to do. Thanks for the help Val!

Comment: As @VineethMohan pointed can  you provide example output for both queries ?

Comment: @keety I can't give the results. it's giving the same for both queries but in the second query is retrieving documents that it shouldn't be there because I have the must_not clause.

Comment: Can be related with the cache? I have cleared the cache but it's still not working.